# Unable to build application after adding telerik references

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I added references to telerik dlls in the code, with copy local set to true. But, when I am building the project I am receiving an error randomly.

```
Error1Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Telerik.OpenAccess, Version=2015.1.220.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.' C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets2689SMS
```

I am not using openaccess assembly at all. I have no idea why this keeps coming randomly. I am not even able to find the dll anywhere to add it to the project.

Comment: May be this little tool can help you in finding what assembly is referencing it: https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy

Comment: Reference: mscorlib
   4.0.0.0 by vshost
   2.0.0.0 by vshost

Reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync
   12.0.0.0 by vshost

Comment: That's the output of the asmspy. It makes no sense.'

Comment: You solved the problem? If so, how?

Comment: Not solved. :/ I just simply deleted all traces of telerik installation, and then manually added reference to the dll alone. I am still unable to use telerik controls by dragging and dropping. But, it works fine if I add the control by typing out the code manually.

Comment: at this link there is a useful ? http://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-build-the-application-after-adding-telerik-references

Comment: I want to use Telerik.Reporting

Comment: That is the thread created by me, actually. Used my boss's account for it, so different name. Anyway, thanks for reminding. I will add the answer here. I totally forgot about it.

Comment: I found a way to get around the issue, by using the old method of referencing dlls. So, that works for now. I hope telerik team fixes this issue though, but I have doubts on their capabilities (considering they don't even have same feature set for same controls across different languages).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the telerik controls by dropping them to designer from the toolbox (just like typical asp.net controls). Somehow in that case, it was referencing the path of the installation folder (C:\ProgramFiles...). That's why it was failing on different PCs wherever the installation path changed (like telerik 2.0.2 instead of telerik 2.1.2).

So, I copied all the dlls from installation path, uninstalled telerik completely. Then I copied the required dll to bin folder and referenced it in solution from there.

Comment: Same method? Or something else?

Comment: I removed some unnecessary dll. And then I copied the required dll to bin folder